# LC Tank Circuit frequency error

Tags: passive-networks

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0RIEe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Please read the LM358 as LM339 as I could not find LM339 in schematic library**

I am designing a LC Tank circuit with comparator to be used in an inductance measurement circuit.

Ideally, when the circuit is charged for a couple of seconds and then the switch disconnected, the circuit frequency should be 13.30kHz according to the resonant frequency formula but when I simulated the circuit, the frequency measured is 220Hz.

Can anybody please check if the circuit is correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your approach, and nothing wrong with schematic simulator.

First let's consider just the tuned circuit you have.

When you try to create a tuned circuit with very large capacitance and low inductance values you have to consider the oscillating current flowing. This will directly define the peak voltage you will get across the tuned circuit.
I've redrawn your schematic to show various currents and the ringing one would expect.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f22jJm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With a 150 Ohm R1 resistor you will get approximately 31 mA through the inductor.
Notice that the diode has to be fast the way I'm driving it and your selection of a 1N4148 would not work  ....I put a BAT54 Schottky diode in it's place. 
FYI your use of a physical switch to charge/trigger is unlikely to provide consistent results as you will get contact bounce making derivation of frequency of the pulse count difficult.

The signal level with a current of 31 mA is under 300 mV as shown below:

[image]

With a 10 Ohm R1 resistor we get about 360 mA in the inductor, and as shown below get a decent number of cycles starting at about 4 V peak when the voltage drive drops.

[image]

The tuned circuit frequency appears in both graphs to be what you would expect, 13.3 kHz.

I'd suggest that if you are trying to design an inbound test jig using this sort of schema for comparative readings.

1. Don't use switches in signal paths, they are not suitable for most test jigs.
2. Keep the current as high as you can to ensure the best signal levels from your tuned circuit.
3. Count ten cycles from the trigger (I used a 10 Hz signal here but you could increase this) so you don't end up with very low signal voltages. (eliminate noise)

As shown by Andy in the other answer you need to detect a bipolar signal, but you don't need to use a dual supply...however it might just turn out to be the easiest approach.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jack...I did redraw the LC circuit part excluding the LM339 comparator and using the resistor value of 10 Ohms as you suggested. I did get a decaying sine wave of 13kHz as expected. I wont be using switch in the actual circuit. The LC tank will be energised momentarily via a PORT pin from a PIC microcontroller and the frequency thus recorded will be used to calculate the inductor value. But I was getting stuck as to why the frequency being recorded was way less than expected. Turns out the LC circuit was not properly designed. Thanks for helping

Comment: If that's the answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit is faulty. During the two second charge period the net voltage across the inductor will be very close to 0 volts because the inductor acts as a short circuit at DC and when you open the switch, L1 and C1 will try and produce a decaying sine wave centred at 0 volts. This means your op-amp needs to be powered from a negative supply as well as a positive supply to avoid either destroying it and/or getting a sensible output: -

[image]

Comment: It seems this characteristic is for LM139 not LM339

Comment: @Dhans no, that is incorrect. Read the top line of the data sheet extract.

Comment: A -5V negative-side supply would seem a sensible approach, but be aware that the LM339 logic output swings awkwardly between +5V and -5V. A LM311 comparator could avoid this problem.

Comment: @glen_geek I agree so maybe tthe best option is to provide a mid-rail that can supply the 33mA without bouncing too much.

Comment: I have checked the circuit simulation in Proteus8. The circuit is working, i.e., when the switch is closed and then opened after a brief period, say for a couple of seconds, I am getting a decaying square wave at the output as expected but the frequency is way low, 203 Hz. According to the calculation of resonant frequency it should be around 13KHz. I will post the scope screenshot in a couple of hours and also try and redesign the opamp negative supply